# What functionality will I lose downgrading jQuery from 2.0 to 1.10?

Tags: jquery

We are implementing a new website that will be used alongside an existing system. The current system uses IE8 but in setting up the new site, jQuery2.0 has been used.

If we downgrade jQuery to 1.10, will we lose any of the functionality?

The blog (http://blog.jquery.com/2013/07/03/jquery-1-10-2-and-2-0-3-released/) isn't very clear.

Is this going to be a complex job to downgrade?

Comment: nothing as far as I know... 2.0 is a trimmer version by removing support for IE7

Comment: Since you are using <IE9 you will need to use 1.10, because 2.0 has a lot of the IE8 and lower compatibility code.  Most of the functionality should be the same, however you will lose some performance on some calls.

Comment: @abc123 This is what I thought but needed to be sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**No.**

jQuery 1.9+ and 2.0+ are the same for newer browsers. The difference between 1.9x and up (including 1.10) and 2.0 and up is the 2.0+ branch gets rid of the extra code that provides support for legacy browsers. For newer browsers, you shouldn't see any difference (except possibly a faster jQuery because of its smaller size.)

Comment: definitely worth to mention that jQuery 1.xx will not be extended with new features that may be implemented in jQuery 2.xx in future releases.

Answer (score 30):

Using conditional comment trick you can serve jQuery 2.0 to +IE9 and jQuery 1.9 to older ones:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 15):

No, currently they are still the same, only that v1.10 has support for IE7 and IE8.
This version will also be maintained and patched with bugfixes, if bugs are reported.

But its API will not be extended anymore. So, if there will be new features in v2.xx, these will not be added to 1.10 with IE support for older versions.

But for now, they are essentially the same, and downgrading should be very easy.

Comment: Things changed and they plan to keep API the same for both versions in jQuery 3, so this answer is actually misleading. http://blog.jquery.com/2014/10/29/jquery-3-0-the-next-generations/